# Ruby send method to Array#map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to alter an array in ruby. Usually I'd do

```
[1,2,3].map{|i| i*3}
```

However I want to use send like I'd use `to_s`:

```
[1,2,3].map &:to_s
```

And I try this:

```
[1,2,3].map &:send(:*, 3)
```

but it returns an error

```
SyntaxError: unexpected '(', expecting $end
[1, 2, 3].map &:send(:*, 3)
```

How would I go about sending this block to map without using `{}`

Comment: It does not make sense. A symbol does not take arguments.

Comment: You can do as below although `a = [1,2,3]
a.map(&3.method(:*)) # => [3, 6, 9]`.. `#send` is not needed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case, you can exploit the fact that multiplication is (or at least should be) symmetric, i.e. that `a*b == b*a`:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(&3.method(:*))
```